# Inserting Data to three linked table with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am inserting data from a dict type object into three different tables in the SQL database. I am using Sqlalchemy as my ORM. My code is working but I think it is not very readable, is it any way to make it more readable or maybe simpler? I am using a lot of `try except` because I don't want my code to fail in the middle and also because all the three tables are related to each other.

My code is below:

```
def upload_fpb_data(data, project_id):
    fpb_count = len(data)
    fpb_added_count = 0
    fpb_children_count = sum(map(lambda x : x['count'], data))
    fpb_children_added_count = 0
    fpb_children_base_color_count = sum([sum(map(lambda x: x['count'], i['children'])) for i in data])
    fpb_children_base_color_added_count = 0
    for parent in data:
        parent_data = parent['data']
        add_fpb = FPB(stockCode=parent_data[0], description=parent_data[1], 
                        longDescription=parent_data[2], altKey=parent_data[3],
                        project=project_id)
        db.session.add(add_fpb)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            fpb_added_count += 1
            for child1 in parent['children']:
                child1_data = child1['data']
                add_fpb_children = FpbChildrenAssociation(ParentPart=child1_data['ParentPart'],
                Component=child1_data['Component'], qty=child1_data['ComponentQtyPer'])
                db.session.add(add_fpb_children)
                
                try:
                    db.session.commit()
                    fpb_children_added_count+=1
                    fpb_children_association_id = add_fpb_children.id
                    for child2 in child1['children']['data']:
                        add_fpb_children_base_colors = FpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation(
                                fpbChildrenAssociationId=fpb_children_association_id,
                                baseColor=child2,
                            )
                        db.session.add(add_fpb_children_base_colors)
                        try:
                            db.session.commit()
                            fpb_children_base_color_added_count +=1
                        except:
                            db.session.rollback()
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    db.session.rollback()
            
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
    return {'fpb':f"Rows Appended {fpb_added_count}/{fpb_count}",
            'fpbChildrenAssociation':f"Rows Appended {fpb_children_added_count}/{fpb_children_count}",
            'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation':f"Rows Appended {fpb_children_base_color_added_count}/{fpb_children_base_color_count}"}
```

if you want to see the data I am working with then here it is:

```
data = [{'table': 'fpb',
 'data': ('XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'SSLDX STERN BOX', '', '20SX200'),
 'children': [{'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'DID-1828A-50-V1.20.001.00', 1.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFH0136SLV', 1.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFN0019', 4.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFN0036', 4.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFN0043', 4.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFN0046B', 4.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFN0091', 4.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RFN0126', 1.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'RPP0134', 4.0],
   'count': 3,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation',
    'data': ['00', '60', '90']}},
  {'table': 'fpbChildrenAssociation',
   'data': ['XPB.20.001.07.200.01', 'X.001.07.44579', 1.0],
   'count': 1,
   'children': {'table': 'fpbChildrenBaseColorAssociation', 'data': ['60']}}],
 'count': 10}]
```

Comment: @BCdotWEB i have changed the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about **data integrity,** that's what **transactions** are for. I don't really see the point of nested try/catch blocks. A single block for the whole procedure would be sufficient.

So, at the start of your try block, you start an explicit transaction using `session.begin()`, you do your stuff and finally you **commit** at the end, or **rollback** in case of exception. That's it.

As an example:

```
# verbose version of what a context manager will do
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.begin()
    try:
        session.add(some_object)
        session.add(some_other_object)
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        session.commit()
```

The source (recommended): [SQLAlchemy - Session Basics](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html)

If you want an all or nothing operation that's what you should be doing. Presently, you are doing regular commits, and it's perfectly possible that the code will fail in the middle. Thus some tables can be populated without matching records in the other related tables.

Just removing those nested blocks should increase readability. Then consider adding some **comments**. And line spacing. The code is a bit terse. Regarding the naming conventions, I am not sure about what kind of data you are handling but I am thinking the names could perhaps be more telling that child or children something ?

Instead of incrementing a counter manually like this:

```
fpb_added_count += 1
```

you could use the `enumerate` function like this:

```
for fpb_added_count, child1 in enumerate(parent['children'], start=1):
```

But your objects may have a len() property already right. Do you really need to keep track of item counts separately ?

This variable `child1_data` does not seem to be really useful:

```
child1_data = child1['data']
```

Why not simply just use `child1['data']`.

Same for `fpb_children_association_id` etc, that makes the code harder to follow for no real benefit I think. There is no real improvement or simplification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not looking to rollback the whole transaction if only one table fails. That's why I added them in a particular order. Do you there is an easier way to do that?

Yes, I would like to keep the track of the counts so that I can tell the user how many of the rows have been added out of the actual number of rows for each table.